# Iptables port redirecting. Rule doesn't work or show up in iptabels

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, port-forwarding, tcp, iptables

I'm trying to redirect some incoming TCP traffic on port 443 to port 999 with iptables in an Ubuntu VM.

I am using `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 999`, but when I enter it it does not show up with an `iptables -L`, nor does it actually work.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you ran `iptables-save` to save this new rule.
What is the output you get for `iptables -t nat -L`?

Comment: A reboot seemed to fix the problem. Thanks for the help anyway. :)